# setUserTrackingMode display troubles sometimes occuring

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, user-location

I have a weird issue (*concerning the displaying of my current location*) with the call of the method of `MKMapView` :

```
- (void)setUserTrackingMode:(MKUserTrackingMode)mode animated:(BOOL)animated
```

My map well display my location with the blue dot, but there is an issue occuring "sometimes" with the center and zooming features of this method :

- Sometimes the view **start zooming and then it quickly come back to it's start position**, so the view is not centered and zoomed on my current location.
- The other times it works : the view is centered and zoomed on my current location.

Note that this issue has not the same occurence between Simulator/iPhone(5).
On my iPhone, this issue only happen when I launch the view for the 1st time. And sometimes, at the 1st time, it works…

See the screen **when it works**, it's well centered :

[image: When it works]

And when **the trouble occurs** :

[image: With trouble]

In the viewDidLoad of my MKMapView, I placed :

```
[map setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading animated:YES];
```

NOTE: `map` has been synthesized.

I also checked in the method :

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateUserLocation : lat : %f, long : %f", userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude,
                                                   userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude);
}
```

And the coordinates are the good ones (thoses of my current location).

I searched and searched on the site, but I couldn't find my answer.

Anyone experienced the same issue ?

I wanted to know if it's a bug or an error from me.

Thanks for ideas and help.

EDIT : A new behaviour just appeared : after have quickly moved back to the starting display location (my issue), the view centered and zoomed on my current position as soon as it moved back !..

And sometimes i get the interference message like there : http://hillcrestlabs.com/makingmotion/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/compass-interference-v2.png.

Maybe my theses issues have a link with this interference problem ?

I tried to get away with my iPhone from computers and working room but the issue is still here… Should I go farther ?

Comment: It seems not to be an interference problem because the simulator use some simulated current position. I really don't know why this happen… :/

Comment: i have this same issue....